# My listview only gets updated when using the debugger

Tags: android, debugging, android-listfragment

Whenever I run my app normally, the listfragment is always blank for the bnf fragment. However, if I go set a breakpoint before the fetch stories method and step through the code line by line, the listfragment gets updated! The last class I pasted is an AsycnTask that gets all the data with which to update the listview. I'm thinking I'm doing something wrong with threading somehow but I'm not sure what's going on. For what it's worth, the first fragment that gets added is also an asynctask and it works fine.

```
public class NasaAppActivity extends Activity implements ActionBar.TabListener{

private Bundle savedInstanceState;
private static View mainView;
private FragmentTransaction ft;
BreakingNewsFragment bnf; //a list fragment
NasaDailyImage ndi; //another fragment

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart(); 
    if(savedInstanceState==null){
        ndi=new NasaDailyImage(this);
        bnf=new BreakingNewsFragment(this);     
        ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.focused_view_container,ndi).commit();
        ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.focused_view_container,bnf).commit();
    }

public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction f) {

    switch(tab.getPosition()){ //switches which fragment is visible
    case 0:
        ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


            ft.hide(bnf);
            ft.show(ndi);
            ft.commit();

           getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();


        break;
    case 1:
            ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.hide(ndi);
            ft.show(bnf);

            ft.commit();
            bnf.fetchStories();
            bnf.updateList(); //updates the list fragment
          getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

         break;
    }

}
```

}

---

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class BreakingNewsFragment extends ListFragment {
    private static Activity mainActivity;
    private static ArrayList<Story> stories=new ArrayList<Story>();
    private static ArrayList<String> storyTitles=new ArrayList<String>();

    public BreakingNewsFragment(){

    }
    public BreakingNewsFragment(Activity mainActivity){
        this.mainActivity=mainActivity;
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    }
    public void fetchStories(){
        RssNewsParser parser=new RssNewsParser(mainActivity);
        parser.execute("");
        stories=parser.getStories();
        for(Story story:stories){
            storyTitles.add(story.getTitle());
        }
        String result;
        result = storyTitles.toString();
    }
public void updateList(){
    String result;
    result = storyTitles.toString();
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(mainActivity,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,storyTitles));
}
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();




    }

}
```

---

```
public class RssNewsParser extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<Story>,String,ArrayList<Story>>{
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    URL newsURL;
    ArrayList<Story> stories=new ArrayList<Story>();
    int eventType;
    int storyCount= -1;
    private Activity mainActivity;

    RssNewsParser(Activity mainActivity){
        this.mainActivity=mainActivity;
    }
    public ArrayList<Story> getStories(){
        return stories;
    }





        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Story> result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            dialog.hide();
        //this.cancel(true);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        dialog=ProgressDialog.show(mainActivity, "Loading", "loading news");
    }
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Story> doInBackground(ArrayList<Story>... params) {
        try{

        newsURL = new URL("http://www.nasa.gov/rss/breaking_news.rss");//set URl                         
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(newsURL.openStream()));//get rss
        XmlPullParserFactory factory;
        factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();//new factory
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp;
        xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        xpp.setInput(in);
        eventType = xpp.getEventType();//returns an int which mean different things (START_DOCUMENT,START_TAG,etc)



    while(eventType!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){//while the document has words

     switch(eventType){

        case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT://beginning of xml
            break;
        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG://case : at beginning of new tag
            String tagName=xpp.getName();

            if(tagName.equals("item")){
                Story story=new Story();
                stories.add(story);
                storyCount++;
                xpp.getDepth();
            }
            if(tagName.equals("title")&& !stories.isEmpty()){
                xpp.getDepth();
                stories.get(storyCount).setTitle(xpp.nextText());
            }
            if(tagName.equals("link") && !stories.isEmpty()){
                stories.get(storyCount).setURL(xpp.nextText());
                xpp.getDepth();
            }
            if(tagName.equals("description")&& !stories.isEmpty()){
                stories.get(storyCount).setDescription(xpp.nextText());
                xpp.getDepth();
            }

            break;

        }
        eventType=xpp.next();
    }//switch   
        in.close();//close BufferedReader
    } catch (MalformedURLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(XmlPullParserException e1){
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e2){
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }     
        return stories;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My listview only gets updated when using the debugger

here

```
    parser.execute("");
    stories=parser.getStories(); //<<<<<<< here
```

you are trying to get `AsyncTask` result back just after executing `AsyncTask` . either use `AsyncTask.get()` method for getting result back and make wait until `doInBackground` execution is not complete or use `onPostExecute` for updating `ListView` with new data returned from `doInBackground`. change your `onPostExecute` as :

```
@Override
 protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Story> result) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
     // get data here
     stories=getStories();
    BreakingNewsFragment.this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(mainActivity,
                         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,stories));
     dialog.hide();

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, so it was trying to get the result before the task was finished?

Comment: @TylerPfaff : yes you are right currently u are trying to get result before finishing the AsyncTask execution this is because doInBackground method always executed in separate  Thread from Main UI Thread . that's why main thread execution is not block . and u are getting empty list

Answer (score 1):

You're treating the fetchStories method as if it were a blocking call.  This means, you're expecting your code to wait until that method finished until calling the next line which calls the updateStories method.  However, since fetchStories works asynchronously, it's not finished by the time you call updateStories.

The way to fix this is to call updateStories from your AsyncTask's onPostExecute method.  The purpose of this method is to allow you to execute code on the thread that launched your AsyncTask (usually the UI thread, so you can do updates) after the task has finished its main work (the stuff you put into doInBackground)

The reason it works when you're debugging is because you are slowing down the execution of your code enough for fetchStories to finish before you call updateStories.  On a device, that won't be the case.

Short answer, update your list from onPostExecute.